# Stripe payment form constantly reloads @stripe/react-stripe-js preventDefault not working?

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, preventdefault

i followed this example https://stripe.com/docs/payments/link/add-link-elements-integration

I see the form where you put in credit card info.
clicking around inside and outside the form, it constantly re-renders, page refreshes.
I dont think the form preventDefault is working.
This issue is occurs in chrome, chrome incognito, and safari.

any idea why page constantly refreshes?

```
// PayScreen.tsx
const stripePromise = loadStripe(config.stripePublishableKey)
export default function CreatePaymentScreen() {
  // this code is updated from the comments below. still same problem.

  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryFn: async () => await createPaymentIntent(), 
    // stripe_client().PaymentIntent.create backend function
  })
  const clientSecret = data?.intent?.client_secret
  const email = data?.customer?.email

  if (isLoading || !stripe)
   return null
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise} options={{ clientSecret }}>
        <CheckoutForm email={email} />
    </Elements>
  )
}
```

```
// CheckoutForm.tsx literal verbatim from https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider
import { useStripe, useElements, PaymentElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js'

const CheckoutForm = () => {
  const stripe = useStripe()
  const elements = useElements()

  const handleSubmit = async (event: any) => {
    // We don't want to let default form submission happen here,
    // which would refresh the page.
    event.preventDefault()

    if (!stripe || !elements) {
      // Stripe.js hasn't yet loaded.
      // Make sure to disable form submission until Stripe.js has loaded.
      return
    }

    const result = await stripe.confirmPayment({
      // `Elements` instance that was used to create the Payment Element
      elements,
      confirmParams: {
        return_url: "https://example.com/order/123/complete",
      },
    })

    if (result.error) {
      // Show error to your customer (for example, payment details incomplete)
      console.log(result.error.message)
    } else {
      // Your customer will be redirected to your `return_url`. For some payment
      // methods like iDEAL, your customer will be redirected to an intermediate
      // site first to authorize the payment, then redirected to the `return_url`.
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <PaymentElement />
      <button onSubmit={handleSubmit} disabled={!stripe}>Submit</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CheckoutForm
```

```
// package.json
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^2.4.0",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "^2.4.0",
```

my problem is different from
[Stripe payment form constantly re-renders using @stripe/react-stripe-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75898162/stripe-payment-form-constantly-re-renders-using-stripe-react-stripe-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its useQuery. changed to useEffect, and its fine

Answer (score 0):

You should just pass `stripePromise` to `<Elements>` directly. There's no need to use `useEffect` and `useState` hooks to set an instance of `Stripe`. Refer to the integration [doc](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react#elements-provider) for more details.

Comment: ok i passed stripePromise directly. The form keeps reloading when i click around.